# `rbind.data.table` refuses to accept numeric vectors

Tags: r, data.table

To build a table for printing, I want to `rbind` a vector to a `data.table`, e.g.:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:5, var1 = rnorm(5), var2 = runif(5))
bind <- c(0, 1, 1)

rbind(dt, bind)
```

But this throws an error:

> Error in `rbindlist(l,use.names,fill)`: 
>        Item 2 of list input is not a `data.frame`, `data.table` or `list`

In this simple case, I can remedy this by specifying

```
bind <- list(0, 1, 1)
```

But things can be more complicated:

```
bind <- list(0, dt[ , .(mean(var1), mean(var2))])
```

Breaks:

> Error in `rbindlist(l, use.names,fill)`:
>        Item 2 has 2 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 3 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument `fill` to `TRUE`.

Of course the problem is that `dt[...]` is as a whole being sent to the second element of `bind`, meaning `bind` only has two elements.

I can remedy this by specifying instead:

```
bind <- dt[ , .(0, mean(var1), mean(var2))]
```

But this becomes messier for more complicated bindings and requires `use.names = FALSE`, which has the potential to screw up the rest of the binding (for example, if I'm binding `rbind(dt1, dt2, c(0, 1, 1))` instead, it's not always the case that `dt1` and `dt2`'s columns are in order; here the solution is `rbind(rbind(dt1, dt2), dt[ , .(0, 1, 1)], use.names = FALSE)`, but again this seems unnecessarily messy.

Why can't we pass simple vectors to `rbind`?

Comment: Why are you rbinding objects of varying lengths and dimensions? Bind has 3 elements. Your table has 2 cols. how can they rbind?

Comment: This is not specifically an issue with `rbind`, this is an issue with `rbind.data.table` since your first parameter is a data.table. Note that `df<-data.frame(id=1:5,var1=rnorm(5),var2=runif(5)); bind<-c(0,1,1); rbind(df,bind)` works presumably how you would expect. But in general the reason you can't bind in vectors is that typically columns in a data.table/data.frame are of different classes and a vector can only hold a single atomic type so usually a rbind doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you really need this all in a single data.table "for printing"? How are you "rendering" this output.

Comment: The error text is very clear. `rbind(dt,as.list(bind))` *does* work. If it's really about printing, that's not what `data.table` syntax is optimized for. Maybe consider a `table` and using the `addmargins` function...?

Comment: @MrFlick of course, I should have been more specific; edited. I'm ultimately TeXing this through `xtable`.

Comment: @Frank unfortunately I sometimes need to add more than one row of numbers. An example I have in mind is trying to stack two tables, one produced with my data, and one of numbers I enter manually from another paper--I want to compare my numbers to those produced by a similar data set.

Comment: @MrFlick it's true that columns are of different classes... but base `rbind` simply casts everything to character if there's a type conflict. (e.g. `rbind(c("some","words"),c(0,1))` That's the behavior I expect here.